# Cross Domain XML parse to PHP

Tags: php, xml, parsing

I am currently working on a project that requires to load a remote XML file from a Cross-Domain site to my PHP document and I am unable to load it as I get an error. I have tried different solutions, but neither of them seems to work. I am using the 
`simplexml` library for the parse action.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://static-m.meteo.cat/content/opendata/maritim_mar_endins.xml');
var_dump($xml);
```

And the result of the parsing is:

```
bool(false)
```

Any suggestions on how could I fix this error?

Comment: I tried your code and its working for me, can you check weather your firewall is prohibiting it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not a cross domain (CORS) problem. PHP runs on the server and the limit has no effect there. Here are other possibilities, like that the server blocks outgoing connections or the called URL blocks connections from specific IPs, needs specific HTTP-Headers (User-Agent) or an Authentication.

Try fetching the data using `file_get_contents()` and increase your error reporting. This might provide you with more information. You can load the result using `simplexml_load_string()`.